# Trouble solving 'source.uri should not be an empty string' in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having trouble solving

> source.uri should not be an empty string

in React Native.

I don't understand where this error comes from. I have 3 **Flatlist** in my component that renders **children** components with props from the **parent** as the URI and none of these is empty.

This is the uri part:

```
<Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={{uri: this.props.url }} />
```

[image]

Comment: Your error is saying that this.props.url is empty. Please show us the whole file where you're rendering the <Image />

Comment: Thing is I have a dozen different files involving images that are being rendered in this view. But even when deleting all images I still get this issue.

Comment: Why isnt the error telling me which file it relates to?

Comment: You should use `url` instead of `uri` in new react.

Comment: @JoelJerushan it actually works, but I can't find any documents on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I managed to fix the issue by adding to the default **INITIAL_STATE** variable that sets the state of my app and the default value before the actions are executed.

So adding the url below was the fix! But could be any url other than a null value.

```
profile: { user: { phone: '', email: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', photo: 'http://www.tiptoncommunications.com/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png', description: '' }, membership: { active: false } }
```

Comment: I added a local photo in my initial state. thank you :)

Answer (score 19):

Here is another solution:

```
<Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={this.props.url ? {uri: this.props.url } : null} />
```

Answer (score 5):

It is likely an empty string is passed to the uri. If you set the uri as an empty string intentionally like myself to not to display any image for this data, use undefined instead or use it like so:

```
<Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={{uri: this.props.url !=="" ? this.props.url : undefined }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way, can be implemented:

```
render() {
     const {imageURL} = this.state;
     <Image source={{uri:imageURL ? imageURL : null}} style={styles.tinyLogo}/>
}
```